# How to get id of saved entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Dynamics CRM 2011 on premise

I can barely believe I can't find this out by Googling. MSDN is useless.

Here is some C# from a plugin:

```
integ_creditpayment creditpayment = new integ_creditpayment();
creditpayment.integ_Amount = totalPay;
//set more properties
context.AddObject(creditpayment);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Now I want to get the value of the id field in integ_creditpayment.

Can I get this immediately from creditpayment.id? (As in, does context.SaveChanges() cause the creditpayment variable to be updated with the new id?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the `SaveChanges()` you can get the record id with:

```cs
Guid justCreatedId = creditpayment.Id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your real code is more complicated, but there is no need to use the context in your example code:

```cs
integ_creditpayment creditpayment = new integ_creditpayment();
creditpayment.integ_Amount = totalPay;
//set more properties
creditpayment.Id = service.Create(creditpayment);
```

You can also use a type initializer and get rid of your object all together if you'd like:

```cs
Guid id = service.Create(new integ_creditpayment
{
    integ_Amount = totalPay;
});
```

`service` in this case is of type `IOrganizationService`